# I am looking for an effective way to share data between python2 and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

First of all. My major code in python2. Recently I was looking for some functionality, after a lot of searching I was able to find libraries in python3.

So, I have written that part of the code in python3.
Now, the next big trouble was data sharing among data sharing. So, I have used os.system() for that along with pickle to share data among both programs.

But, I found this very ineffective way to do. It makes the program slow. My program is time critical. Is there any effective way to do the same which is faster.

Comment: Is there a reason not to port all of your code to Python 3?

Comment: It rather depends on the nature of your program. Perhaps you can have a Python 3 worker running permanently and have the two programs communicate over sockets/[ØMQ](http://zeromq.org)/[MQTT](http://mqtt.org)/[WAMP](https://wamp-proto.org)/whatever.

Comment: Ya. The python2 code is quite bulky. plus it has used opencv2.4 which is I guess only supported by python2. It will be more comfortable if I take 3 part 2. Currently, i am working on that. If that doesn't work out, I guess that I have to go the other way. (I cannot live with the code with poor performance)

Comment: Thanks, deceze i will take a look at the sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You can share data with an in-memory database like [Redis](https://redis.io/) or a message broker like [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/features.html)

Comment: Thanks Nikos, I will take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer you're looking for but this is the solution going forward: you should port your "major code" written in python 2 to python 3. The [end of life for python 2](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/#update) is in 2020, which is [less than 2 years from now](https://pythonclock.org/). As time passes it will only be harder to move to python 3 and more insecure to keep using 2. Also note that you were forced to switch to 3 because of third-party libraries; this is the opposite of the usual effect where people stick with 2 due to lazily maintained dependencies.

You mentioned in a comment that your python 2 code uses OpenCV 2.4. Well, that's really good news! Firstly, OpenCV has been supporting python 3 for a very long time! Secondly, your work sounds mostly numerical, which would make porting the native python parts to 3 trivial (something that the `2to3` tool could do for you, perhaps entirely). I'm thinking adding missing parentheses to `print` and the like. You would also be able to use modern python patterns only available in python 3, especially its newer versions.

I'm aware that upgrading your code to use a newer version of OpenCV is *not* trivial, but as an occasional user of OpenCV I would find this still the easiest and most easily maintainable solution by far. Consider it an investment (a really good one, with no risk and very high return).

Comment: Careful about division when porting numerical code! `7 / 2` is different in Python 2 and 3